# Action link with 3 parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on an mvc .net web application. Is there a way to pass 3 parameters to an action link?

Comment: please provide some code sample.. as to what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the code below

I am sending 3 parameters to an Action, these parameter include

- int id_diff
- string pseudo
- string contenu

  ```
  @Html.ActionLink("Text", "ActionName", new { id_diff = 33, pseudo = "bye", contenu = "haha" })
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, actionlink takes routevalues object or dictionary

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "NewComment", new { id_diff=somevalue, pseudo=somevalue, contenu=somevalue})
```